PostGIS: DEALLOCATE addfeatures returned 7 [ERROR: prepared statement "addfeatures" does not exist when using pgbouncer connection pool
I have the same issue/question like this one: PostGIS: DEALLOCATE addfeatures returned 7 [ERROR: prepared statement "addfeatures" does not exist
The error message copied from the QGIS debug panel is below.
The error message only appears when I connect to PostGIS through a connection pool. The connection pool I use is the one from digitalocean managed database cluster. They use pgbouncer. When I connect QGIS directly to the database without a connection pool, all works fine.
What I have unsuccessfully tried so far are different configurations of the connection pool with different connection limits bigger than number of cores of my notebook (here I read in a post from Andreas Neumann that QGIS is spanning one connection per CPU Core https://lists.fossgis.de/pipermail/fossgis-talk-liste/2022-October/012238.html )

Connection pool in session mode

Connection pool in transaction mode


If the error message is right, somehow the prepared statement is not found when using a connection from a pgbouncer connection pool no matter if the connection pool is in session or transaction mode.
Any hints?
PostgreSQL Version is: 15.4
QGIS Version is: 3.34.3-Prizren
{
  "Error": "Erroneous query: DEALLOCATE addfeatures returned 7 [ERROR:  prepared statement \"addfeatures\" does not exist\n]",
  "Initiator": "QgsPostgresProvider",
  "Location": "spostgresprovider.cpp:2812 (addFeatures)",
  "Provider": "postgres",
  "SQL": "DEALLOCATE addfeatures",
  "Started at": "**********",
  "Total time (ms)": "12",
  "URI": "service='*****'"
}


can you explain why this is a different question to the one you link to? the answer to that suggests that there may be a prior problem to this exception

The other question does not mention that a connection pool could be in the play. Initailly I wanted to add my question to the other one but StackExchange told me that it is not nice to anwser a question with an other one. That is why I created a new one.
